# How to know the geographic distribution of the users in a given SE?

Tags: discussion

I would like to know what is the geographic distribution of the users in a particular SE. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can to a limited extent use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) for that. The users table contains a field location but is free text and user maintained.

Here is the [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/763381) for Stack Overflow:

```sql
select '[Overall]' as [Location as entered by users]
     , count(*) as [#times that location was used] 
from users
where location is not null
and location <> ''
union all
select location
     , count(*)
from users
where location is not null
and location <> ''
group by location
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: You're the master of SEDE here.

Comment: @iDebug sede - rene ... looks suspicious